# mod_rewrite mod_pagespeed RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-pagespeed

I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

The server admin has installed Google mod_pagespeed and of course, because the folder doesn't exist, it logs an error every time as it tries to access `/mod_pagespeed_beacon` (and no stats are logged).

What `RewriteCond` do I need to add (and where) so `/mod_pagespeed_beacon` will work?

Comment: FYI, you can contact us at mod-pagespeed-discuss@googlegroups.com and list issues at http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally you can whitelist all resources with `pagespeed` in the name with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pagespeed
```

See the [new section in the mod_pagespeed FAQ](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/faq#mod_rewrite)

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer to my question. Just add the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mod_pagespeed_beacon
```

I don't think it matters where in the list of rewrite conditions is goes.

-- Edit

I also needed the following to access the statistics:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mod_pagespeed_statistics
```

Comment: Nice solution, we'll keep in mind if we see this issue again.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. Here is an updated rewrite code that works for other related URLs too... `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mod_pagespeed_[a-z_]+$`

Comment: This answer is now out of date with mod_pagespeed 1.9, see more recent answer by sligocki.

Answer (score 2):

I have vBulletin 4 Suite + vBSEO
Found that this line in .htaccess sorted out the problem

```
# mod_pagespeed
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(mod_pagespeed_statistics|mod_pagespeed_beacon) [NC]
```

Place it before this line in

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ vbseo.php [L,QSA]
```